# Which of the following sets are closed under the binary operation $*$ defined as: $a*b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Which of the following sets are closed under the binary operation $*$ defined as:
$$a*b=\frac{a+b}{1+ab}$$

$1.\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x\geq 0\}$

$2.\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|x|>1 \}$

$3.\{x\in \mathbb{R}:|x|<1 \}$

I have proved that first is closed.

Second is not closed if we take $a=b=2$

About third I am unable to prove or disprove it,  need help about the last option.

Answer (score 3):

As a hint for the last one, what can you say about $(1-a)(1-b)$

Comment: Sorry but I not pick your hint.Can you explain  little bit more?

Comment: Well the two factors are positive, so the expression is $\gt 0$. Now expand and rearrange $(1-a)(1-b)\gt 0$

Comment: Thank you so much I got it,it proves that 3rd set is closed under given binary operation.